# Sending more than one image (Discord JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have tried to make a command that sends more than one randomly picked images from an array of images.

The following code works, but it only sends one single image:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("es!jefelegion")) {
    let jefe = [...];
    let image = jefe[Math.floor(Math.random() * jefe.length)];

    console.log(image);
    message.channel.send(image.text, {
      files: [
        {
          attachment: image.link,
          name: 'name.jpg',
        },
      ],
    });
  }
});
```

How can I change this to make that send two or more images?

Answer (score 2):

The `files` option accepts an array, so you can just add more items in there. If you want to pick random images from a list, you can create a helper function, like `pick()` below.

```js
function pick(arr, size) {
  if (typeof size === 'undefined') {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }

  if (size > arr.length) {
    size = arr.length;
  }

  const copy = arr.slice();
  const items = [];

  while (size--) {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    const item = copy.splice(i, 1)[0];
    items.push(item);
  }

  return items;
}

const images = [
  {
    attachment: './path/to/image1.jpg',
    name: 'Image #1',
  },
  {
    attachment: './path/to/image2.jpg',
    name: 'Image #2',
  },
  {
    attachment: './path/to/image3.jpg',
    name: 'Image #3',
  },
  // ... rest of images
];

message.channel.send('Wooo, more than one files ', {
  files: pick(images, 3), // picks 3 random images from the `images` array
});
```

And the result:

[image: bot]

Comment: Yes , but ,  I want to send 2 or more random images with a constant . I mean , that each time you use the comand , the bot send you two or more   random different images from a const with thousand of images.